# No DB in Local www and on Android device with SQLite plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I use sqlite plugin for my app, with a DB including 3 tables.
On desktop, everything is working, the app access' to data. But, i didn't find the DB in folders, and when a run on my device, there is no db in app/package folder.

Here is my code:

app.js :

```
var db=null;

var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
...

if (window.cordova) {
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", location: 1, iosDatabaseLocation: 'default' }); //device
}else{
db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser


}
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Utilisateur (id integer primary key, cleapi integer, siret integer)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Avis (id integer primary key, siret integer, note integer, date text, reference text, titre text, texte text )");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InfosAdherent (id integer primary key, notegenerale integer, nbavis integer, avispos integer, avisneu integer, avisneg integer, datedebut text )");

});
})

.controller('CtrlConnexion', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope,$http, $cordovaSQLite) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

if (window.cordova) {
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", location: 'default', iosDatabaseLocation: 'default' }); //device
}else{
db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser


}
var query = "INSERT INTO Utilisateur (id,cleapi,siret) VALUES (1,1234,73282932000074)";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
console.log("ok uti");
alert("ok uti");
}, function (err) {
console.error(err);
console.log("pas ok user");
});

var query1 = "INSERT INTO Avis (id,siret, note, date, reference,titre, texte) VALUES (1,73282932000074,3,'24/12/2013','REFREDF','Titreavis','texteavis')";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query1).then(function(res) {
console.log("ok avis");
alert("ok avis");
}, function (err) {
console.error(err);
console.log("pas ok avis");
});

var query2 = "INSERT INTO InfosAdherent (id,notegenerale,nbavis,avispos,avisneu,avisneg,datedebut) VALUES (1,4,6,2,3,1,'11/04/2011')";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query2).then(function(res) {
console.log("ok infos");
alert("ok infos");
}, function (err) {
console.error(err);
console.log("pas ok infos");
});

    $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
    $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
    $scope.$apply();

    // Si on est en ligne
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
        $scope.isOnline = true;
        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();            
        $scope.$apply();
    })

    // Si on est hors ligne
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
        console.log("got offline");
        $scope.isOnline = false;
        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        $scope.$apply();
    })

    console.log(FileTransfer);
}, false);
})
```

login.html (nothing special)

```
<ion-view class="panelogin" title="Login" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">


<ion-content style="margin:30px;" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false"  overflow-scroll="false">


login form
...
  <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="LogIn()">
    Go !
  </button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

index.html :

```
<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>




<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>



<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I tried many solutions (in device ready, db init args location, ...) but nothing works. There is no my.db in my www folder, think it is magic that I can see table content through chrome.

Hope somebody can help me ^^

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging your app with Chrome, you can see your SQLite db by opening the developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) then going to the Resources tab, on the left panel there's an option called Web SQL, all your DB should be listed there.

In devices is not that simple, to see the db on an Android device this one should be rooted, and you will need a root file manager to access the following folder:

> data/data/[packagename]/databases

Answer (score 0):

Ok for Android, so the file is on the device but we can't see it ? (in ios platform my.db is)